# Image doesn't fill width even though width is set to 100% on larger monitors

Tags: html, css

I have this in my CSS:

```
.cover .cover-image {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size:100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

I also have this in my HTML:

```
<div class="cover-image" style="background-image : url('./bkg.jpg');">
```

bkg.jpg is a 1939x1131 image - bigger than any of my monitors. On my smallest (1280x1024) monitor, it displays fine:

[image]

On my medium (1440x900) and large (1920x1080) monitor - both of which are smaller than the image - it shows a bit of white between the image and the scrollbar:

[image]

Why does this show, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried stripping out all other css and readding it chunk by chunk to ensure nothing else is interfering?

Comment: I have, and it still does it.

Comment: Have you set `margin` and `padding` to `0` for the ancestor elements up to, and including, the `html` root node?

Comment: @DavidThomas That didn't fix it.

Comment: Does it happen for all 3 browsers?

Comment: Then you need to provide enough code to reproduce your problem, ideally with a live demo.

Comment: @hogarth45 Firefox and Chrome yes, IE displays it on the left for some reason... [image](http://i.imgur.com/yyNCNny.png)

Comment: @DavidThomas Do you not reproduce it? And I just started the website tonight, but if you want to see it it's [here](http://chipperyman.com/dota)

Comment: Check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/4g9x4cjb/1/

Comment: @bayblade567 What's that have to do with my question?

Comment: No, if you want us to see it add the relevant, minimal ("[mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)") code here, to your question. Don't expect us to go to your site to see it, especially since, once the problem is solved, the broken code will no longer be present.

Comment: @DavidThomas I only gave that link because you asked for a live example. And I don't really know what other relevant code there is, as far as I'm aware that's the only relevant code. I'll check again to make sure there's no other code involved in this issue, give me a sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your image source

https://chipperyman.com/dota/bkg.jpg

You have a white bar on your image.

Comment: That's so weird, the file I uploaded doesn't have that... But yes, I suppose that was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Chipperyman hadn't shared any image or URL here, how did you got his image?

Comment: @bablu he put a link in the above comments "show 7 more comments"

Answer (score 0):

double on background-size your code, please fix background-size:100%, otherwise you will get issue.. And i mean you not need using background-size because your image already bigger than your screen..

you need normalize html, body

```
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I have that in my CSS already, what do you mean about double on background-size?

Comment: background-size:100%;
background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

there.

Basically you are having an absolute positioning bug here. Just add '*left: 0px;*' to your **.cover .cover-image** selector as per following:

```
.cover .cover-image {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size:100%; /* old browser fallback, but I'd delete it */
  background-size: cover; /* duplicate of background-size */
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here is also a jsfiddle example of fixing it: http://jsfiddle.net/webyourway/868L6hhg/